# Cannot run Mocha test from WebStorm gutter (left side bar)

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm

I want to run Mocha tests from the WebStorm gutter (the green triangle icons on the left side, by the line numbers).

But these green green triangle icons are absent.

[image]

How to setup it?

```
WebStorm 2018.3.3
Build #WS-183.5153.33, built on January 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.2

➜ ~ node -v
v10.15.0

➜ ~ mocha --version
5.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic used for determining what test runner is available for a given test file is based on dependencies declarations in `package.json`. Declaring `"mocha"` as a dependency in `<project root>/package.json` should enable mocha runner in `<project root>/**/*` files.
If no test runners are found, there will be no icons in the gutter